# getJSON error in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, firefox, getjson

I have a form which lets the user enter their search term and it then gets passed to another page via jquery ajax post. On the process page I have the following code:

```
<?php $searchText = $_REQUEST["searchText"]; ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.facebookfeed').append('<p>Loading your results</p>');
  var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=';
  var url = url+searchText.value;
  var url = url+'&type=post&limit=60&callback=?';       
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
    console.log(data);
        var html = "<ul>";
            if (json.data == ''){html += '<li><h2>Sorry, no results were found. Try with another search term.</h2>'; }
        $.each(json.data,function(i,fb){
            if (!fb.message == ''){
                html += '<li><div class="box">'
                html += '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/'+ fb.from.id +'" target="_blank"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + fb.from.id + '/picture" /></a>';
                html += '<p><span class="name"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/'+ fb.from.id +'" target="_blank">' + fb.from.name + '</a></span>  <br />';
                html += fb.message;
                html += '</p></div></li>';

            }
            });
        html += "</ul>";
        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
                $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
                                                              });
        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);

    });


</script>
```

This code works properly on Chrome and Safari but in Firefox I am getting the following error:

```
Error: searchText is not defined
```

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sure looks like the variable `searchText` is supposed to be an input in your form.  Is this the case?  Where are you defining that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your searchText variabale is in php, but you are trying to use it in a javascript. Try transferring it to a javascript variable `var searchText = "<?= $searchText?>";`.

Then your javascript will look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.facebookfeed').append('<p>Loading your results</p>');
    var searchText = "<?= $searchText?>";
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=';
    url = url+searchText;
    url = url+'&type=post&limit=60&callback=?';   
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        ...    
    });
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Need to do a bit more reading on working with PHP and jQuery. :D